# How to disable syntax highlighting in Markdown fenced code blocks

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

For indented code blocks, adding `<!-- language: lang-none -->` disables syntax highlighting. What about for fenced code blocks? Can I use `lang-none` or `none` in fenced code blocks too?

Which of the below is correct?

#1:

````
```lang-none
=== some text here ===
```
````

#2:

````
```none
=== some text here ===
```
````

Comment: TL;DR: use option #1